# Max number of skill points in Elder Scrolls Online?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I wonder what is the max number of skill points you can get ?
There are levels, skyshards, dungeons, quest, achievements I guess.

And if you can max everything on your skill panel ?

Comment: Just added an answer to your second question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Tamriel Journal](http://tamrieljournal.com/skill-points-in-eso/) seems to have the most up to date table of skill points.

**~304 is their estimation.**

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║  Skyshards           107 ║
║                          ║
║  Levels               58 ║
║                          ║
║ AVA Ranks             49 ║
║                          ║ 
║ Zone Quest lines      48 ║
║                          ║
║ Group Dungeon Quests  16 ║
║                          ║
║ Public Dungeons       16 ║
║                          ║
║ Main Story Quests    ~10 ║
║==========================║
║ Total               ~304 ║
╚══════════════════════════╝
```

Obviously it may be a while before anyone 100%s the game, as well as talk of secret skill points. So getting an accurate answer will have to come from Zenimax.

To answer your second question which I didn't see, there are ~422 skill slots. So you are 120 skills points short to max everything. Keep in mind that includes both Vampire and Werewolf, which you can only have one and Emperor.

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ to answer both your questions. you do not get a skill point for level 1, also level 50 and veteran rank 1 are the same level, so thats 1 equaling 58. yes that is 107 skillpoints from skyshards.

Comment: @Paralytic I thought I saw info that indicated the Emperor skill line to be 100% free, no points needed, similar to the first skill in a given racial line. Is that not true, or is the total skills number a bit lower than you thought?

Comment: @BillyMailman ill look into it further.

Comment: Honestly having a hard time finding anything that says whether or not they are free passives. @billymailman

Comment: @Paralytic It's not exactly a skill line that's easy to get. UESP is saying it's free, and everywhere else I've found has been from well before release, or else utterly vague.

Comment: @BillyMailman well either way its 6 skills. so a low impact

Comment: I improved the post, feel free to roll back if you don't like it, but I think it looks much nicer and having the source is necessary actually because copyright law and such.

Comment: Regarding the talk on secret skill points you can mention the possible 2 from mages guild quest.

Comment: I have 316 so far. i have a few public dungeons to finish and haven't got the bosses in wrothgar yet. I've also not finished every vet dungeon yet. Also only 8 in assault/support rank.http://imgur.com/RuDM6CQ

Answer (score 3):

You can't yet, but from what I've heard you're able to get about 300 skill points, which should be enough to unlock pretty much everything you're interested in.

They already said that future updates will bring new skills, but new skill points as well.

Also keep in mind that you're able to reset spent points without losing progress, in case you ever run out of points and absolutely want to try something specific.