# How do I gain skill points from public dungeons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In this question, someone explains that you can get skillpoints from public dungeons:

[Max number of skill points in Elder Scrolls Online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164595/max-number-of-skill-points-in-elder-scrolls-online)

However, it is not explained how you actually gain those skill points and how you can keep track of them. Can someone explain this please and, if applicable, add the names of Dungeons that reward Skillpoints for completion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Final Boss in every Public Dungeon, once you kill this boss you get a Skill Point. I believe each Final Boss in Public Dungeons have an achievement associated with them, if you are concerned about keeping track of them.

[image]

The two achievements I have arrows to are prime examples of achievements that track the defeat of Final bosses in Public Dungeons.

I have broken them down to the easiest most comprehensive form possible. Zone, Name of dungeon, person/persons you have to kill or event you have to complete for skillpoint.

### **Ebonheart Pact**

-*Stonefalls*, **Crow's Wood** -- 
Destroy the South Wraiths to summon Ghyslain and then slay him.

-*Deshaan*, **Forgotten Crypts** -- Eradicate the Kwama infestation and kill the Kwama Guardians.

-*Shadowfen*, **Sanguine's Demesne** -- Kill fight-Master Grel and his adepts.

-*Eastmarch*, **Hall Of The Dead** -- Defeat Reynir the Destroyer and his minions.

-*The Rift*, **Lion's Den** -- Kill the Lonely Giant and his angry Mammoths.

### **Daggerfall Covenant**

-*Glenumbra*, **Bad Man's Hallow** -- Slay the Giant Snake Mother

-*Stormhaven*, **Bonesnap Ruins** -- 
Slay the Eternal One

-*Rivenspire*, **Obsidian Scar** -- 
Slay Zilbash the Deciever.

-*Alik'r Desert*, **Lost City of the Na-Totambu** -- Solve the Puzzle of the Guardians.

-*Bangkorai*, **Razak's Wheel** -- Defeat the Flesh Atronach.

### Aldmeri Dominion

-*Auridon*, **Toothmaul Gully** -- Destroy Bloodroot and its guardians.

-*Grahtwood*, **Root Sunder Ruins** -- Complete the Root Sunder Ruins Group Event

-*Greenshade*, **Rulanyil's Fall** -- Defeat the undead hordes of Hergor the Fallen.

-*Malabal Tor*, **Crimson Cove** -- Kill Flat Tooth and his boys

-*Reaper's March*, **The Vile Manse** -- Defeat the damned creations of Graccus' frost experiments.

### **Coldharbour**

**Village of the Lost** -- Defeat Zatalguch in its subterranean lair.

16 in total.

Comment: Those aren't "final bosses", they're optional group challenges. You don't have to beat them to complete the dungeon (there are typically two quests (or quest chains), one leading you in there and one to discover while inside), plus the group challenge.

Comment: He isn't asking how to complete the dungeon, he is asking how to get the skill point as well as how to track it. And yes they are the final boss @Mario

Comment: I have unaccepted this answer. Reason is simply that I was keeping track of skillpoints and bosses killed and none of the 4 PUblic Dungeons I did the last few days rewarded a skillpoint simply for completing them. Also seeing that there are only 16 SP for Dungeons, I would rather like a list of those Dungeons that actually reward SP.

Comment: @Assylum maybe you should edit the question to reflect those changes.

Comment: @Assylum Then you probably did Delves, or smaller public dungeons. I was talking about the larger group public dungeons. I can add the list later today

Comment: @assylum the list of Public dungeons, anymore fine print you didnt mention?

Comment: @Paralytic No need for that attitude dude. I was assuming it means every dungeon, since that is what you said. Every dungeon is something completely different than "only those 16 dungeons".

Comment: @Assylum, I said every Public Dungeon, I was wrong to assume everyone knew what i ment as the terminology for the smaller dungeons are Solo Dungeons or Delves, as they are also public.

Answer (score -1):

It is not true that you can get a skillpoint from every public dungeon. It is however true that there is a Skyshard in every public dungeon (those marked with a torch on your map). You may know that you have to collect 3 Skyshards to get a skillpoint, so the public dungeons indeed contribute to your overall skillpoints.